# mvc contrib grid - pager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I am using the mvc contrib grid and generate the pager like this:

```
<%= Html.Pager((IPagination)Model) %>
```

This produces something like this:

Showing 11 - 20 of 200 first | prev | next | last

Is there a simple way to produce something like this which shows 'neighboring pages':

Showing 11 - 20 of 200 first | prev | 1 2 3 4 ... | next | last

In other words to allow the user to 'jump pages'. I hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVCContrib's Pager doesn't support this. You could take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/) for a sample implementation.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I will have a look at this.